# Play! Framework 2.0 paths - play run vs play start

Tags: playframework-2.0, production-environment

I'm storing files to a folder in a play! project and I have a question about paths. My solution is working, but I think the solution is sub optimal.

My current solution:

```
public static String getStoragePath(){
    String pubDir =  Play.application().configuration().getString("pathToFiles");

    if(Play.isProd()){ 
        String prodDir = Play.application().configuration().getString("productionPath"); 
        //prodDir variable is "target/scala-2.9.1/classes"

        return Play.application().path().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + prodDir + "/" + pubDir;
    }else{
        return Play.application().path().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + pubDir;
    }
}
```

My question:

I do it like this because the paths are different when running "play run" and "play start".
Is there a way to avoid using this if-block? I dont want to be dependent on the productionPath string in my configuration file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the conf file is the way to do it. Just use a different conf file for your production enviroment and you will not need to have a bunch of if(isProd...) checks in your code.

Play 2 has ability to use alternative/extending configuration files as [described in documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ProductionConfiguration) (***Specifying alternative configuration file*** section). Additionally you can create simple bash script (or .bat file in Windows) to start the application in desired mode without need to specify alternative file each time.

Comment: What if tomorrow, your userbase has grown and you have to deploy your application on another server? Will you add an additionnal if to know if it's instance 1 or instance 2 of your production server? No clearly, you have to use the conf files for this kind of problems.

Comment: Agree with @Jakob, using dedicated, additional conf files on different machines and/or modes is optimal way to do that.