# Paths in Play 2.x

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have a Play! application that generates .png image files as part of a visualization process that my web client then displays. I thought I had the write paths set up correctly but had only tested in DEV mode. Once I switched over to production mode, my web client is attempting to grab the files from the correct location but my Java code is no longer writing my files to the correct location.

Basically in DEV, the write path is something like:

```
project/application/public/images/image.png
```

In Production, the write path needs to be something like:

```
project/application/target/scala-2.10/classes/public/images/image.png
```

I sort of gathered the following code to specify the file write location would just work?

```
//Set up paths correctly regardless of where the application is running
String basePath = Play.application().path().getPath();
String fullPath = basePath + "/public/images/image.png";
```

Well, unless I've mucked up something else, it isn't working as I expect - the path isn't different in DEV vs. Production. It always ends up like this:

```
project/application/public/images/image.png
```

Various posts (such as: [Play! Framework 2.0 paths - play run vs play start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745429/play-framework-2-0-paths-play-run-vs-play-start)) suggest specifying the pathing in a production version of my .conf file...and I should start my play application using that...  But honestly, is there some reason that some variant of the code I posted shouldn't just work?

EDIT:
It's possible this really doesn't work the way I expect because dynamically generated files generally can't be served back since all of the assets in the public/ folder are compiled into a .jar file.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this code to write the file :

```java
String basePath = Play.application().path().getPath();
String fullPath = basePath + "/public/images/image.png";
```

You always get the **root project dir** path when using `Play.application().path().getPath();` So, whatever you are on production or development mode you should get path for the root project directory and you always write that file on `rootprojectdir/public/images/image.png` (as the value of `fullpath` variable). You may try to do as suggested on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745429/play-framework-2-0-paths-play-run-vs-play-start#answer-13746259) or on the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745429/play-framework-2-0-paths-play-run-vs-play-start#question) that you have read before. It is your preference.

---

> #### Note:
>
> To be note here, because you place your generated files on such directory. If `play clean` or `play clean-all` commands are executed, all files on `target/*` files and folder would be deleted. So, be aware!